# Bind a repeater with static data when data is not available in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to bind a repeater with some fixed values when datatable is empty.

My code is

```
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
   DataTable temp = new DataTable();
   temp.Columns.Add("banner_id");
   DataRow drs = temp.NewRow();
   drs["banner_id"] = 1;
   temp.Rows.Add(drs);
   temp.AcceptChanges();
   rpt_slider.DataSource = temp;
   rpt_slider.DataBind();
}
else
{
   rpt_slider.DataSource = dt;
   rpt_slider.DataBind();
}
```

I want to show at lest one record when `datatable` is empty

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: it shows nothing when data is empty

Comment: where you have written this code? have you checked the `dt.Rows.Count ` what is the value?

Comment: and what are you getting in `dt.Rows.Count` have you checked? and what is the purpose of `temp.AcceptChanges();` it is not required.

Comment: 0 when data is empty and at that time i want to bind with a static record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void getdata()
{
    property.banner_id = 0;

    property.banner_type = "Primary";
    DataSet ds = bal.getdata_view(property.banner_id, property.banner_type);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    ViewState["getdata_primary"] = dt;
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        rptMain.DataSource = bal.getdata_view(property.banner_id, property.banner_type);
        rptMain.DataBind();

        lblmsg.Text = "";
        lblmsg.Visible = false;
        Button5.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

you need to make this changes in code of getdata() please change it...